# Symfony2 twig path - wrong generated URL behind

Tags: symfony, proxy, path, twig, relative-path

I have a problem with generating relative URL in symfony 2.7 project

My project is hosted behind a proxy that redirect URL to the target VM, like this - `example.com/oblounge/bo/` to `vmhostname/`

All my URL are generated in relative

Here is my problem

For example when I'm on this page

http://example.com/oblounge/bo/admin/articles/actualite?section=127

All generated likns are malformated, the "/admin/articles" is duplicated

http://example.com/oblounge/bo/admin/articles/admin/articles/actualite?section=127

Note: The problem is occurred only for rendered controllers

The render action

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Back/Article/Article:sectionsArticle', { 'rubric': 'actualite' })) }}
```

The rendered twig

```
{% for section in sections %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('back_post_list', {'rubric': 'actualite'}) }}?section={{ section.iden }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{{ section.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

My routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

The prefix of my admin controller

```
/**
*  @Route("/admin")
*/

class ArticleController extends BaseArticleController
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you give a look at your *routing.yml* file that is referenced within your bundle.
If you've already defined a prefix for the route in the ***routing.yml*** of you **app/config** there is no need to repeat it in the routing of your bundle , otherwise there will be a duplication of prefixes as in your case.

Example:
This is the **routing.yml** in the App\config folder

```
tutoLexikTestBundle_parents:
    resource: "@tutoLexikTestBundle/Resources/config/routing/parents.yml"
    prefix:   /parents
```

And this is the one of the bundle

```
parents_show:
    path:     /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "tutoLexikTestBundle:Parents:show" }
```

I don't need to repeat the prefix 'Parents' in the path

Comment: Yes but i have not repeated prefix